# Adding items in a nested list?

Tags: python, list, loops

I have this code for adding up items in a nested list:

```
list1 = [[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6]]
total = 0
for i in range(0, len(list1)):
    print 'len(list1)', len(list1)
    print 'i=', i
    for j in range(0, len(list1[i])):
        print 'j=', j
        print 'list1i', list1[i]
        total += list1[i][j]
        print 'sub-total=', total

print 'Final Total:', total
```

When implemented, this runs:

```
len(list1) 2
i= 0
j- 0
list1i [1, 2, 3]
sub-total= 1
j- 1
list1i [1, 2, 3]
sub-total= 3
j- 2
list1i [1, 2, 3]
sub-total= 6
len(list1) 2
i= 1
j- 0
list1i [4, 5, 6]
sub-total= 10
j- 1
list1i [4, 5, 6]
sub-total= 15
j- 2
list1i [4, 5, 6]
sub-total= 21
Final Total: 21
```

It works, but I don't understand WHY. Like, why does i= 0 at the beginning? Shouldn't "i" be the elements of the list? I thought that's what happens when you run a for loop. Same with j. Also, what do i and j pertain to? I've been looking at this code for hours and searching for videos, can't seem to find an explanation for this. If anyone could explain the elements of this code for me, it would honestly be so much help. Thank you.

Comment: You should direct these questions to whoever wrote this code.

Comment: FWIW, I'd replace those loops with `for sublist in List1: for item in sublist: total += item`. What you have now, `for i in range(len(...))`, is a code smell. Calling `range()` in that context is usually unnecessary.

Comment: I recommend the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/index.html).

Comment: Or the [official Python2 tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/), since you are using Python2.

Comment: use a debugger, or `print` statements for variables at points within the code that you don't understand usually helps..

Answer (score 0):

**i** is an index in the main list; **j** is an index into each sub-list.  The difference between an index and the elements themselves is

```
for i in range(0, len(list1)):
    # work with list1[i]
```

versus

```
for elem in list1:
    # work with elem
```

You can do this either way, depending on whether you need to know the index of each element as you process it.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(0, len(list1)):
```

makes `i` into the result of [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range), which gives a list of numbers from the first up to, but not including the last.

`i` and `j` are indexes into those lists. It is treating this like an array, which is usually a holdover from someone new to Python trying to apply their old language skills, where `i` and `j` would represent `x` and `y` values in a 2 dimensional array.

Instead, a better way in python would be:

```
total = 0
for sublist in list1:
    total += sum(sublist)
```

or even

```
total = sum(map(sum, list1))
```

Comment: Don't call it `list` or you'll mask the built-in. Also, `sum(map(sum, lst))` would be shorter as well as faster.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Good point. And I corrected it to what the OP was using `list1`.

Answer (score -1):

*why does i= 0 at the beginning? Shouldn't "i" be the elements of the list?*

The statement `for i in range(0, len(list1)):` sets `i` to increment from 0 to (1 -the length of the list) in the outer for loop. The value of `i` is used as an index to the elements of `list1`.

Note that the length of `list1` is 2 - i.e. it has two elements which are themselves lists. The first element is `[1,2,3]` and the second `[4,5,6]`.

The same explanation above goes for `j`. In the code you submitted, `j` is incremented from 0 to 1-(length of `list1[0]`) in the first iteration of the outer loop, and from 0 to 1-(length of `list1[1]`) on the second iteration of the outer loop. The combination of `i` and `j` are used to index the actual numbers stored in the nested lists.

From your question you seem to expect the values of `i` and `j` to reference the actual elements of the list. You could do this, but the syntax will be slightly different as shown below:

```
list1 = [[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6]]
total = 0
for i in list1:
    print 'i=', i
    for j in i:
        print 'j=', j
        total += j
        print 'sub-total=', total

print 'Final Total:', total
```

Comment: Okay, I see that. But could you please explain what total=0 does? Thanks

Comment: `total = 0` creates a variable named total and initialises its value to 0. This means that before you enter the for loops and start adding the entries in the list the value of total is 0.